# Media upload on Wordpress changes title of image

Tags: uploads, media

I have a rather random and annoying issue when uploading images for my products.  If I upload one item it changes the title to mde or rhrn or a strange variation of letters.

I've tried using the bulk uploader and the same thing happens but not for every image:
[image]

It seems to pick at random which image to change the titles on.

I tried renaming my plugins folder, then installing a default theme in case it was something to do with that, but the exact same thing happened.

I've also tried installing plugins that help with renaming media files on upload but none of them helped.

Has anyone came across this before in Wordpress?  Or know how to stop this happening?

Comment: Based on the images that have proper names above, I don't think this is a character set issue... ...and if they were duplicate names I don't think it would just give them random strings, usually it just appends a `-#.jpg` to the end of the file.  Does your hosting have some sort of integrated CDN or are you maybe using a CDN plugin?  I know that sometimes CDNs will rename things, but I've never seen that with images.  I have seen this sort of thing with CSS and JS files and some caching and auto-optimization plugins and CDNs, but never with images.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen when there is metadata in the jpeg file, but I'm not sure why WordPress Media Uploads decides to use this information as its title to override the media filename as its title as what we have come to expect when images are uploaded.

For example, if you open the image under Adobe Bridge or some other product that lets you edit the IPTC data then you may find that image of your has the headline of 'mde' or 'rhrn' that you have mentioned.